# Setting ANSI Padding OFF with ALTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I need to turn ANSI PADDING from ON to OFF on an existing field of a table without creating a new table. Is there a way to do this through an ALTER command?

Thanks!

Comment: And the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql) is quite clear: "This setting affects only the definition of new columns. After the column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting when the column was created. Existing columns are not affected by a later change to this setting."

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this with just `ALTER`. Like the identity property, collation and some other bits, whether a column applies ANSI padding or not is not something that can be altered after the fact.

You can still do it without creating a new table altogether, but not without creating a new column:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;
ALTER TABLE T ADD C_badpad CHAR(16) NULL;
EXEC('UPDATE T SET C_badpad = C;')
EXEC sp_rename 'T.C', 'C_old';
EXEC sp_rename 'T.C_badpad', 'C';
EXEC('ALTER TABLE T DROP COLUMN C_old;')
ROLLBACK; -- COMMIT;
```

But, if you value your sanity, don't do this. Rewrite the client code that wants this so it does its own proper trimming, because the very ability to have `ANSI_PADDING` set to `OFF` is deprecated, with good reason. Almost everything expects `ANSI_PADDING` to be `ON` these days, so having it `OFF` for a specific column is likely to break clients that aren't expecting it. Even if you think you're solving a problem now, you're likely going to end up with bigger problems in the future.

`ANSI_PADDING` is only there as a compatibility tweak for very old software that just doesn't know any better (and will likely want the whole database to be created with `ANSI_PADDING = OFF`). Don't use it in new development, and certainly don't use it for just one column.

Comment: If you come across this years later, it depends.  If importing data that was exported as char() for everything, the trimming via ANSI Padding off can be handy in a staging table using varchar types.  Or if you have a untouchable COBOL process inserting records with a buffer big enough for anything possible, it might be nice to not keep the fat.  (Instead,  have a job doing a daily trim() to free up many GB.  Perhaps a trigger....  A column with ANSI Padding OFF would have been ideal.)

Comment: @RandyinMarin: I would argue that if you really need this ability specific to certain columns, and are categorically unable to change client software to apply this logic, then a trigger makes more sense than relying on what is almost certainly an obscure toggle, as it puts the logic front and center. In particular, you can create a view with a `CHAR` column that uses an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to direct things into a trimmed `VARCHAR` instead. In cases where that's not good enough, a dedicated DB with the setting off for every column (and cross-DB queries) is arguably still clearer.

Comment: Being clear in our system would be an anomaly and likely confuse people.  :)  I agree it would be clearer to use a trigger.  Likely more efficient as well.